# custom foreign key values based on constrain

Tags: django, database, algorithm, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a model as:

**PRODUCT_EXPIRY MODEL:**

```
product_id = model.IntegerField()
expires_in = model.IntegerField() --days count
```

And another model as:

**PRODUCT:**

```
product_id = model.IntegerField()
expires_in = model.IntegeField(blank=True)  --days count
name = model.CharField()
price = model.FloatField()
...other fields
```

What I want is, let a store add products, and here `expires_in` (days count) of product is optional, he can choose to add it manually while adding product or if he doesn't, then the expire in is entered from `product_expire` model, mapping via `product_id`.

 **BUT** consider following cases:

1. Milk X has 3 days of expiry.
2. Milk Y has 60 days of expiry.
3. Cocoa powder has 6 months of expiry date.

When a store enter a product, lets suppose he gets it at least after 10 days from manufacturing date. So the `expire_in` while adding cocoa powder shall be `60-10 = 50 days` i.e. products which has expiry greater than say 30 days. Where as milk van delivers milk daily, so product with expiry less than 30 days will have expiry as same without any change i.e. while adding Milk `expires_in` for Milk X will be `3 days`. How can I do so? Does `Product` model `expired_in` has to be a Foreign Key?

**Eg:** Suppose we know coke expires in 1 month, so if a store forgets to enter expiry date, the automatic expiry date added shall be 20 days. So as later I can notify store if product will soon expire. But for Milk expiry added shall be without any change.

Or do I have to build a custom algorithm for this via overriding the save function of product model?

What I am thinking by now is:

- keeping it as `IntegerField` and adding another field as `DateTime`,
  if date time field is entered, use that, else use the `expired_in`
  field, and overriding the save function.
- Handling blank values later via pandas or some custom python script.
  But is there an easy way?

Comment: better use expiry date and and then you can calculate how many days are left imagine an employee to count how many days are there till the product expires... it will slow down the entries, better use expiry date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i see the model should look like

```
class Product(models.Model):
    """
    """
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Procuct")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Products")
    quantity = model.IntegeField() #Imagine ther are 50 packs of coffe that have arrived today
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_("name"))
    prise = FloatField()
    expiry_date = models.DateField()
    arrived_at = models.DateField()
    status = 'not_expired'


    def __str__(self):
        return '{name} {expiry_date}'.format(name=self.name, expiry_date=self.expiry_date)
```

better use Expiry date instead exprites_in because if an employee should type everythin will be more time consuming instead of just typing the expiry date

then if you want to check the products that will expire the next 5 days just

import date

```
def checkExpiringProducts(days)
    return Products.objects.filter(status='not_expired',expiry_date__lte=date.today()+datetime.timedelta(days=days)
```

if you call

```
checkExpiringProducts(5)#gives you the products that are expiring next 5 days
```

you should put `status` though and check every day if there is  a product with `expiry_date` today or tommorow to make it's `status expired`